# Minimize programs as an icon to the desktop

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons, minimize

I am currently using Ubuntu 16.04. There is something in Xubuntu that I love, and it's an option to minimize an open application as an icon on the desktop.

[image: in desktop preference]

When I was a Windows user I used a program that minimized programs as thumbnail on the desktop. This option is very useful when you have lots of programs open. I was wondering if there's any option to bring this feature to Unity?

Comment: At first glance, I thought the linked dupe is what you mean, but is it?